# How to convert blaze data objects to json?

Tags: python, blaze

While trying to use json.dumps in blaze error occurs saying TypeError: object is not JSON serializable.

```
data = Data("employee.json")
json.dumps(data)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't directly convert it to JSON.

Alternate way is as follows :

```
fields = [] # Create an empty list to hold the field names
for fieldName in data.fields: # Iterate the field names 
    fields.append(fieldName) # Add to the list

result = []        
for row in data: # Iterate each row
    currentRow = {} 
    count = 0 
    for value in row: 
        currentRow[fields[count]] = value # Add each value with corresponding key from fields
        count = count + 1
    result.append(currentRow) 
print(json.dumps(result))
```

Answer (score 0):

Because it's a **Blaze Data object**. Objects with their own functions and objects, you cannot fully encode to json. Read: [How to make a class JSON serializable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3768895/python-how-to-make-a-class-json-serializable)

---

If you just want to see variable information use `pprint` function.

Answer (score 0):

If you want an interactive view of your JSON file, just evaluate its name. You'll get the equivalent of `print data.__repr__()`

```
from blaze import Data
from blaze.utils import example

data = Data(example('accounts.json'))
data

#    amount     name
# 0     100    Alice
# 1    -200      Bob
# 2     300  Charlie
# 3     400   Dennis
# 4    -500    Edith
```